# ld cannot find -l<library>

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, linker, shared-libraries, ld

I am having trouble installing pyipopt on ubuntu 12.04.  During linking, I receive the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcoinhsl
```

Even though I know that this library is installed and the .so and .la files are available in `/home/mostafa/MyBuilds/CoinIpopt/build/lib/`

does anyone have a solution for this?

below is the complete return of running setup.py build:

```
root@ubuntu:~/MyBuilds/pyipopt# sudo python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'pyipopt' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/mostafa/MyBuilds/CoinIpopt/build/include/coin/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/callback.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/callback.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/mostafa/MyBuilds/CoinIpopt/build/include/coin/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/pyipopt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/pyipopt.o
src/pyipopt.c: In function ‘set_intermediate_callback’:
src/pyipopt.c:452:15: warning: variable ‘myowndata’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relrobuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/callback.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/pyipopt.o -L/home/mostafa/MyBuilds/CoinIpopt/build/lib/ -lipopt -lblas -lcoinhsl -lcoinmetis -llapack -ldl -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pyipopt.so -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/home/mostafa/MyBuilds/CoinIpopt/build/lib/
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcoinhsl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 8):

> **[-Ldir](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)**
>       Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.

Comment: @Jivan you should set the folder/directory where the library lies, that is what -Ldir stands for. If the folder where `coinhsl` is called `/home/mostafa/MyBuilds/CoinIpopt/build/lib/` then this switch should look like `-L/home/mostafa/MyBuilds/CoinIpopt/build/lib/`. The thing is, this switch is used, so this is not the case. Or it needs another folder to be set! Anyhow, this answer is not good for this kind of question.

Answer (score 2):

You may install your coinhsl library in one of your standard libraries directories and run 'ldconfig` before doing your ppyipopt install

Comment: could you please tell me how should I install it and where are the standard libraries directories? In fact coinhsl is one of the libraries installed and used by IPopt (this a mathematical optimization tool) so I don't know how to install it individually?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with another library and the reason why it didn't found it, was that I didn't run the make install (after running ./configure and make) for that library. The make install may require root privileges (in this case use: sudo make install). After running the make install you should have the so files in the correct folder, i.e. here /usr/local/lib and not in the folder mentioned by you.

Answer (score -5):

you can add the Path to coinhsl lib to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. May be that will help.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/xx/yy/zz:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

where `/xx/yy/zz` represent the path to `coinhsl` lib.

Comment: Actually, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` does not affect the way how libraries are found at *link* time, but at *run* time.