# problems in installing pyipopt

Tags: python, gcc, ubuntu, linker

I have problems with installation pyipopt. The problems is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12107422/1082727). `python setup.py install' contains next output.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lipopt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcoinmumps
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcoinmetis
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status
```

I installed ipopt using synaptic package manager and I found 
next files `/usr/lib/coin/libipopt.la`, `/usr/lib/coin/libipopt.la`

I tried this

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/xx/yy/zz:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I also tried run `ldconfig`.

May be I did something wrong but it did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a non-standard directory where you installed (e.g. into ~/bin/ipopt/), you will have to specify those directories to the compiler so it will find the libraries and header files.

`C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/bin/ipopt/include/coin/ LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/bin/ipopt/lib/ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/bin/ipopt/lib/ python setup.py build`

I still get the -lcoinmumps and -lcoinmetis error, however, because I don't have these libraries. I opened a bug here: https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt/issues/12